# Swipe to delete in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a [Simple Note Android App](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-simple-note-android-app-using-mvvm-and-room-database/). Now I want to swipe to delete items.
I've added this function at the end of NoteAdapter.kt class

```
 fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
    allNotes.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

Then I created a class **SwipeToDeleteCallback**` that extends **ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback**  it is shown below:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class SwipeToDeleteCallback(private val adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>) :
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ) {
    private lateinit var mAdapter: NoteAdapter

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
        mAdapter = adapter as NoteAdapter
        mAdapter.deleteItem(position)
    }
}
```

When I swipe it to the left, even though it disappears, if I go back and come, it will appear again.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSuJy9SfzvFqbcWKhs-a3NtYQicyCFo8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting an items shouldn't happen only in the adapter. Instead, you need to delete it from the database, using your ViewModel's delete function. Based on the code in that tutorial, this should be all you need to do. The repository will update the `allNotes` LiveData, so your observer in your Activity will pick up the change and refresh the adapter for you.

By the way, the way you're using that `lateinit` property is convoluted and unnecessary. Just make your `adapter` property the right type to begin with.

Add a function in your adapter that can accept delete requests. You can use the existing listener since it already supports deleting:

```
fun deleteItemAt(position: Int) {
    noteClickDeleteInterface.onDeleteIconClick(allNotes[position])
}
```

Then call this in your swipe callback:

```
class SwipeToDeleteCallback(private val adapter: NoteAdapter) :
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    //...

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        adapter.deleteItemAt(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the item in an adapter then you have to write like this

// USED TO delete the item by swapping
class SwipeToDeleteCallback(private val downloadAdapter: DownloadAdapter,private val binding: ActivityMultiurlBinding) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

```
override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    downloadAdapter.remove(position)
    setVisibilityForNoDataFound()
    //To do undo action on deleting the item using snackbar action
   /* val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        binding.root,
        "Url at position- $position deleted",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
    )*/
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        binding.root,
        "Url deleted",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
    )
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4DB6AC"))
    snackbar.setAction("Undo") {
        downloadAdapter.undoDelete()
        setVisibilityForNoDataFound()
    }
    snackbar.show()
    setVisibilityForNoDataFound()
}


// it is created for when no data is available to show the text
private fun setVisibilityForNoDataFound(){
    if (!downloadAdapter.getItems().isNullOrEmpty() ) {
        binding.tvNoData.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.downloadbtn.isEnabled = true

    } else {
        binding.tvNoData.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.downloadbtn.isEnabled = false

    }
}
```

}

and in activity you have to call like this
SwipeToDeleteCallback(downloadAdapter, binding)